# How to know OpenShift 3 fetched latest source code?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

Getting error when building `Node.js`, but it seems builder does not load source from `BitBucket.

Pressing `rebuild`, but in first line it refers some old commit, why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't press `Rebuild` on a specific build number as that will use the same commit as last time that build was run. Click on `Builds->nodejs6` and click on the `Start Build` button for the top build configuration.