# How to reach process.env.OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR in OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-3

Earlier in `OpenShift` `Node.js` app the `process.env.OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` environment variable was available. No I migrated to `OpenShift 3`, and I get error.

```
var apn = require('apn');
var optionsP = {
    token: {
        key: process.env.OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR + 'APNsAuthKey_AQ34EHZCDQ.p8',
        keyId: "AQ34EHZCDQ",
        teamId: "AQUJ3H44A4",
    },
    production: true,
};

var apnProviderP = new apn.Provider(optionsP);
```

---

```
/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/apn/lib/credentials/token/prepare.js:15
      throw new VError(err, "Failed loading token key");
      ^
VError: Failed loading token key: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'undefinedAPNsAuthKey_AQ34EHZCDQ.p8'
    at prepareToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/apn/lib/credentials/token/prepare.js:15:13)
    at config (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/apn/lib/config.js:42:31)
    at new Client (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/apn/lib/client.js:11:19)
    at EventEmitter.Provider (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/apn/lib/provider.js:12:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/app-root/src/server.js:26:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under OpenShift 3, if using the bundled S2I builders for different languages, in most cases your application source code will reside at the directory `/opt/app-root/src`. There is no environment variable specifying what the directory is.

To confirm what the directory is, you can use `oc rsh` to get an interactive shell in the container for your application and then run `pwd`. Normally the default directory is where your application code is.

Comment: Fine, corrected, but seems `OpenShift` does not fetch source, do you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46136375/why-openshift-gear-use-so-much-space

Comment: What about `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT`, `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP`, are these environment variables available?

Comment: No. If ``OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT`` is not set, fallback to using port 8080. If ``OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP`` is not set, fallback to using ``0.0.0.0``.